# getting TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list when trying to add text from 1 file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got 2 text files with lists `text1.txt`

```
Pig
Goat
Duck
Cow
Chicken
Sheep
Horse
```

and `text2.txt`

```
Lydia
Marie
Mike
```

What I want to do is add the text of file 1 after the second line of file 2
like this:

```
Lydia
Marie
Pig ---> list will be added here
Goat
Duck
Cow
Chicken
Sheep
Horse
Mike ---> old list continues
```

I wrote a the following script as suggested on this site:

```
with open("text1.txt", "r") as f1:
    t1 = f1.readlines()
with open("text2.txt", "r") as f2:
    t2 = f2.readlines()
t2.insert(2, t1)
with open("text2.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.writelines(t2)
```

and getting the following error:

```
    f2.writelines(t2)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
t2.insert(2, t1)
```

you're creating a nested list. `t2` looks like

```
["Lydia", "Marie", ["Pig", "Goat", "Duck", ...], "Mike"]
```

`writelines()` expects a flat list of strings, when it gets to the nested list it can't write it.

If you want to splice into the list rather than inserting a nested list, use a slice assignment.

```
t2[2:2] = t1
```